# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlinx/coroutines/Dispatchers

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library, kotlin-coroutines

I have a library that uses Kotlin Coroutines and uses the CoroutineScope as

```
private val coroutineScope by lazy(mode = LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    }
```

When I use the library in other projects I am getting error:

```
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ssss.ssss-X44QPiLhKdl-D6eyVAYkOA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ssss.testauthenticater-X44QPiLhKdl-D6eyVAYkOA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
```

I have added `-keepnames class kotlinx.** { *; }`
 in my consumer pro guard file as well.

Does anyone have similar issue? I am using coroutine 1.3.3 in android.

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/657#issuecomment-450914323

Comment: @Quantum_VC: I have : 

`# region Coroutine
# ServiceLoader support
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {}

# Most of volatile fields are updated with AFU and should not be mangled
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
}
# endregion Coroutine`

In my pro guard files but still no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sometime with help of link posted by @orest-herdil above, I figured out the issue was the dependency of my library module were not added in the POM file generated while bundling the AAR file. So I updated my maven publish code as:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "com.mylibrary"
            version "1.1.1"
            artifactId "awesome"

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each { dependency ->
                    final dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dependency.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dependency.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dependency.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The part **pom.withXml { .... }** will go through all the dependency in my library module and add them in generating **POM** file one by one. As of now the compile is already deprecated, I am going through **implementation** dependency only.

Answer (score 9):

Can you please use this version and try again:

```
kotlin_coroutinesVersion = "1.2.1"

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutinesVersion"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutinesVersion"
```

Comment: Did you use the dependency I shared?

Comment: Yes. They are: 

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.1"

Answer (score 1):

ClassNotFoundException can appears due to wrong generation of pox.xml file, which contains dependencies graph of the library, here is a script for publishing library to local maven repo and generating pom.xml file:

https://gist.github.com/Robyer/a6578e60127418b380ca133a1291f017

For applying it to library need to add publishMavenLocal.gradle to library project and put this line at the bottom of library build.gradle: apply from: 'publishMavenLocal.gradle'.

Also for testing it from local maven repo there should be additional identificator in test app gradle file -  transitive = true, like this:

`implementation ('com.example.android:library:0.0.1-library@aar') { transitive = true }`